# Rails : How to display web page without using scafold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a web application in Rails. When user is log in, user must be able to acccess to a web page where he can see some informations. So i create a link from menu like this :

```
<li><a href="/users/ask">Ask data</a></li>
```

Here is my routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

...  
  as :user do
    get 'users/candidat/sign_up', to: 'user/registrations#new', as: :candidat_registration
    get 'users/recruteur/sign_up', to: 'user/registrations#new', as: :recruteur_registration
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "user/registrations", sessions: "user/sessions" }

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do

    put "recommand", to: "users#recommand"

    get '/users/ask' => 'users#ask'

  end

  get "/dashboard" => 'dashboard#index'
  root to: "home#index"

end
```

Here is my web page app/views/users/ask.html.erb:

```
<p>
    Ask Data here
</p>
```

But when i click in the link i cannot access to my web page.

[image]

Here are raltives log :

```
Started GET "/users/ask" for ::1 at 2016-04-13 10:50:49 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"ask"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :set_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

I don't know really RoR but i think it's about configuration in routes.rb. I always generate page with scalfolding. On this page i don't need CRUD features. What wrong please ? If you could suggest me some resources, blog post to understand the problem i have, thanks.
Am i obliged to pass request in a controller ? User need to be connected to access to my web page.
Is it possible to just configure routes and display ?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I dislike people who upvote questions without explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its a routing error. Try changing

```
get 'askrecommandation' => 'users#ask'
```

to

```
get '/users/ask' => 'users#ask'
```

Comment: I am redirected to the home page because i have a 302 error.

Comment: @Pracede Can you update your question with the server log generated? That will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Pracede Try moving `get '/users/ask' => 'users#ask'` above `resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: Your log file is matching users/ask to the users#show controller action. This is because in the Rails routes file, the precedence of route matching is from top to bottom, so if you do what Pavan says it should map to the ask method.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I discover that the redirect to show was made in controller in ask method. I delete the ask method and it works.